# PHPExcel array_filter() error

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am currently using PHPExcel to generate an excel document off of a template I currently have. My idea is that the database will update the template, maintaining its current format, and pass the file to a user for download.

The problem is that when I try and do this (using the basic practice code, shown below) I get the following three errors:

```
Warning: array_filter() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in D:\web\htdocs\dew\root\Welsh\Scorecard\Classes\PHPExcel\Worksheet\AutoFilter.php on line 663

Warning: array_filter() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in D:\web\htdocs\dew\root\Welsh\Scorecard\Classes\PHPExcel\Worksheet\AutoFilter.php on line 664

Warning: array_filter() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in D:\web\htdocs\dew\root\Welsh\Scorecard\Classes\PHPExcel\Worksheet\AutoFilter.php on line 665
```

Lines 663-665 in AutoFilter.php

```
$arguments['date'] = array_filter($arguments['date']);
$arguments['time'] = array_filter($arguments['time']);
$arguments['dateTime'] = array_filter($arguments['dateTime']);
```

My test code:

```
<?php

require('/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php'); 

$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load("test.xlsx");
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('F8','YES_IT_WORKED');

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save("test2.xlsx");

?>
```

Now, when the code is finished running, it does generate the `xlsx` document. However, this document has the majority of all the cells hidden. The first row is visible, but all rows between 1 and 86 are hidden.

---

---

**The following is what I found to solve my problem:**

The excel document I am using has a LOT of filters and odd excel-specific formatting. PHPExcel may not have been able to handle all of these conditions, is my theory. Telling the code to autofilter your excel document fixed the issue with me, such as follows:

```
<?php

require('/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php'); 
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load("test.xlsx");
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('F8','YES_IT_WORKED');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setAutoFilter($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->calculateWorksheetDimension());
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save("Archives/test2.xlsx");

?>
```

amphetamachine's answer also taught me that [this](https://gist.github.com/h3xx/3eb045d30e3e22817587) change in `AutoFilter.php` fixes the problem (see his answer, below).

Comment: Is that really all the code? There's nothing there that would set any Autofilter, or hide any rows.... if you're having problems, please provide a real working example, because the "test code" you've provided certainly doesn't demonstrate the symptoms that you're describing

Comment: Looks like the PHPExcel devs were being lazy and using `[]=` on a non-existent array slot. Since it never appends to it, the array is never created and causes the warning.

Comment: @amphetamachine - if you can point me to the relevant piece of code (that you've obviously found) then I will stop being lazy and fix it; but I cannot replicate this error with the code provided

Comment: OP: Apply [this patch](https://gist.github.com/h3xx/3eb045d30e3e22817587) and it'll fix your warnings.

Comment: @MarkBaker That is all the code in `index.php`. There are no other relevant PHP files other than those in PHPExcel.

Comment: @amphetamachine That was one way of figuring out the problem! I'll update OP to show the other as well. Thanks guys!

Comment: Of course, having a copy of the original test.xlsx to know what it contained might help diagnose the root cause

Comment: I think the excel was the problem. I apologize, but I cannot give you a copy of the document @MarkBaker. However, I'll post what I found fixed it. It's a very easy fix.

Comment: I've seen the fix, though I'd rather correct the root cause: clearly the original file had a badly-formed autofilter

Comment: @amphetamachine - post your "patch" as an answer, it's worth the upvote, but I'll look to the reader to disable invalid autofilters as a more permanent fix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warnings are caused by PHPExcel 1.8.0 not initializing array indexes before using them. In order to get rid of them, apply [this patch](https://gist.github.com/h3xx/3eb045d30e3e22817587):

```diff
diff -ru pex.orig/Classes/PHPExcel/Worksheet/AutoFilter.php pex/Classes/PHPExcel/Worksheet/AutoFilter.php
--- pex.orig/Classes/PHPExcel/Worksheet/AutoFilter.php  2014-03-02 15:27:06.000000000 -0600
+++ pex/Classes/PHPExcel/Worksheet/AutoFilter.php   2014-11-11 15:34:53.582219599 -0600
@@ -634,6 +634,9 @@
                    } else {
                        //  Filter on date group values
                        $arguments = array();
+                       $arguments['date'] = array();
+                       $arguments['time'] = array();
+                       $arguments['dateTime'] = array();
                        foreach($ruleDataSet as $ruleValue) {
                            $date = $time = '';
                            if ((isset($ruleValue[PHPExcel_Worksheet_AutoFilter_Column_Rule::AUTOFILTER_RULETYPE_DATEGROUP_YEAR])) &&
```

Comment: @MarkBaker There's [nothing wrong with being a lazy developer](http://threevirtues.com/). I meant it with the highest respect.